# Error while trying to use Grove Temp module on SnapDragon 410c w 96 boards /sensors-mezzanine

Tags: javascript, qualcomm

Whenever I try to run my JS code, I get an error saying I am passing Illegal arguments for construction of `_exports_GroveTemp`

Code:

```
var mraa = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mraa');
var groveSensor = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jsupm_grove');
console.log(groveSensor)

// Create the temperature sensor object using AIO pin 0
var temp = new groveSensor.GroveTemp(1)
console.log(temp.name());
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error?